# Search or Joins to be used for a complex condition logic - BigQuery

Tags: sql, join, search, google-bigquery

I'm looking for some help with this kind of logic.
I use BigQuery and I have 2 tables:

[image]

[image]

The goal is to show value from 'Performance' column.
I try to build conditional logic which requires these 2 tables.
In steps:

1. Find **first row** with 'Employee name' from 1st table in 2nd table:

- firstly by trying to find it in Name1 column from 2nd table;
- **if** it's **not** there, try to find it in Name2;
- **if** it's **not** there, try to find it in Name3.

2. If the row has a match with 2nd table try to connect Client IDs;
3. If the row still has a match with 2nd table try to connect Territory.
4. Show Performance in the 1st table.

It's important to **not duplicate** records, so if the name was found in Name1 column, then don't search it further in the Name1 column and Name2, Name3 columns.
In this example only Diana (that was found in Name1, 1st row) with Client ID 887 and Territory USA has a complete match.
Ana and Tina were found in Name2, but Client IDs were different.

Thank you in advance for any hint.

Comment: So if there isn’t a complete match don’t show anything? Please update your question with the SQL you’ve managed to write for yourself and explain what the specific issue is that you are facing

Comment: What is the expected result of your example?

Comment: The expected result is to show Performance 'High' for Employee Diana in the 1st table. If there's not complete match then show nothing, just NULL. I'd need some hint to write SQL, because I don't know which direction I should follow... For sure not just single LEFT JOIN; maybe 3 LEFT JOINS (depends which column Name is taken) or maybe Array can be used here, but I'm not experienced with them.

Comment: Can you confirm whether the answer below solved your issue or not ?

Answer (score 1):

Not sure I understood your requirements clearly, but you might consider below.

```sql
-- sample data
WITH table1 AS (
  SELECT 'Ana' Employee_name, '25' Client_ID, 'UK' Territory UNION ALL
  SELECT 'Diana', '887', 'USA' UNION ALL
  SELECT 'Tina', '94', 'UK'
),
table2 AS (
  SELECT 1 Row, 'Diana' Name1, 'Ana' Name2, 'Tim' Name3, '887' Client_ID, 'USA' Territory, 'High' Performance UNION ALL
  SELECT 2, 'Lisa', 'Diana', 'Ana', '25', 'Brazil', 'Medium' UNION ALL
  SELECT 3, 'Rose', 'George', 'Tina', '94', 'Brzail', 'Low' UNION ALL
  SELECT 4, 'Diana', 'Tina', 'Jose', '887', 'USA', 'Medium'
)
-- query starts here
SELECT t1.*,
       ANY_VALUE(t2.Performance HAVING MIN (
         SELECT offset FROM UNNEST([Name1, Name2, Name3]) name WITH offset
          WHERE name = Employee_name
       )) Performance
  FROM table1 t1 LEFT JOIN table2 t2
    ON t1.Employee_name IN (Name1, Name2, Name3) 
   AND t1.Client_ID = t2.Client_ID
   AND t1.Territory = t2.Territory
 GROUP BY 1, 2, 3;
```

**Query results**

[image]